# SwiftUI/macOS app – NSRunningApplication.current.activate called but icon still last in list when Cmd-tabbed

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm loading a preferences window in the AppDelegate of my new macOS/SwiftUI app.

Callling `NSRunningApplication.current.activate(options: [.activateIgnoringOtherApps, .activateAllWindows])` brings the window to the foreground to the user can see it but when I cmd-tab to switch applications, my app is the last one in the list.

Here's my code:

```
@objc func preferences() {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(state)

        // Create the window and set the content view.
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Arch OS System Preferences")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    
        NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
        
        NSRunningApplication.current.activate(options: [.activateIgnoringOtherApps, .activateAllWindows])
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil) // tried this, didn't work
    }
```

How can I ensure that my app is first in that list of icons?

Thanks!

Comment: Not reproducible with regular application. How do you call it and what kind of application you have?

Comment: Called via `menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Preferences", action: #selector(preferences), keyEquivalent: ""))` which is set in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. It's a macOS app using SwiftUI. Building a menu bar app

Comment: Aha... menu bar app... that's the reason.

Comment: I use other menu bar apps where when I bring up their preferences, their icon unhides and is first in the cmd-tab app list though